# Why a "'NoneType' is not iterable" error when I am not iterating?

Tags: python, iterable

When running the following script

```
dictlist = [
    {'a': 'hello world', 'b': 'my name is Bond'},
    {'a': 'bonjour monde'}
]

for d in dictlist:
    if 'Bond' not in d.get('b'):
        print d
```

I expected the output to be empty (the first dict does no match, the second one is missing the key `'b'`) but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/mytest.py", line 7, in <module>
    if 'Bond' not in d.get('b'):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I am confused: why is there a `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` error while I am not iterating (at least on that line)?

I am sure this is an obvious error but the more I look at the code, the less chances that I see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second iteration, `d` will be `{'a': 'bonjour monde'}`, which doesn't have the key `b`. 
`d.get('b')` will return `None` as `dict.get` will return `None` if the key is not found. And `in` operator treats the RHS as an iterable. That is why you are getting this error.

You can simply avoid that, like this

```
for d in dictlist:
    if 'b' in d and 'Bond' not in d['b']:
```

Comment: Thank you. All responses are great -- thanks for the extra bit (the default value would not help as it would match the `if`)

Comment: @WoJ No, the default values alone will not match. Please let me know if you have understood it differently.

Comment: if I use `if 'Bond' not in d.get('b',"")` then when `'b'` does not exist, an empty string will be returned, which will match the `if 'Bond' not in` -- which is not what I want (`'b'` is not present at all, so the test (from the logic perspective) is void). **Your code is OK**: i) `'b'` must exist so that ii) it is checked for `'Bond'`

Comment: @WoJ Oh, if that was your usecase, then you are perfectly correct sir.. :) But this will also work equally fine for this particular case, `if 'Bond' not in d.get('b',[]):` because, it returns an empty list and `Bond` will not be there in the empty list, so the condition will fail. :)

Comment: yes, absolutely, the code is OK and the condition will fail on the default empty string. What I meant is that, from a design/logic perspective I did not want it to fail when there is no key to check -- and your code example exactly does this (check only if there is a key.

Comment: My error intially came from the fact that when I discovered the get method (a while ago) I liked the fact that it returns a `None` when there is no key, making constructions like `if d.get('mykey') == 3:` elegant (they work correctly when the key does not exist). I extended this to the `in` operator without realizing that I am now iterating (over, potentially, a `None`)

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed *iterating* since that's the way operator `in` works. When you do: `if 'Bond' not in d.get('b'):` Python will look for `'Bond'` inside the left operand (`d.get('b')`). `d.get('b') == None` in the second entry hence the exception.

You can pass a second argument to [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.get) which would be interpreted as the default value to get in case of not finding the element to ease this `if` clause:

```
if 'Bond' not in d.get('b',[]):
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `d.get('b', '')` instead of `d.get('b')`.

By default [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) returns `None` if the key you provide does not exist, which is not an iterable or has any method to call. So simply pass an extra argument to `get` to avoid the default return value `None`. See the docstring:

> D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.